# How to change the default temporarily folders on Android Studio?

Tags: macos, android-studio

I have some projects in a folder that is synced with DropBox. For those projects that build with Android Studio the synchronization take ages to complete because of all the binary intermediate and generated files the IDE saves to the project folder. With Xcode, it wasn't a problem because it keeps all the temporary files somewhere outside the project folder.

Is there a way to change the default settings for the path where Android Studio saves all the temporary files? Can this be done for only some projects?

I currently have Android Studio 2.3

Comment: You mean the `.class`, `.apk`, ... files? This might be a generic Gradle setting.

Comment: @C-Otto pretty much everything inside the folder build/